# Change the clipboard register's name

Tags: neovim, register, os-clipboard

To use Neovim with my system clipboard I have to use the `+` register which I find inconvenient. When I type something like `"+p` I have to bounce my pinky all around. Is there a way to change the register it is bound to? For example to the `j` register so I could `"jp` to paste from the system clipboard.

I don't want to use `set clipboard=unnamedplus` because I still want it to be a specific clipboard that I have to intentionally use, so I don't accidentally overwrite it, for example when using `dd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a vim and neovim solution, you can get pretty close with the following maps:

```
nnoremap "j "+
xnoremap "j "+
inoremap <c-r>j <c-r>+
```